# Hiding redirect pages from MediaWiki search

Tags: search, mediawiki

I'm running a wiki using MediaWiki, and when I search for a page the results are clogged with redirects from various capitalization redirects to a page when I only want the result page to appear in search.

Although I want the redirects, is there a way to prevent them from appearing in the search results?

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki used to have an option for suppressing redirects pages from search, but it was removed in version 1.23.   From their [search API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search):

> **srredirects**: Include redirect pages in the search. From 1.23 onwards, redirects are always included. (Default: false) (removed in 1.23)

Comment: Do you know of any extensions that could achieve the same effect?  Also, the pages I want to hide all share the same category, so is there a way I can exclude a specific category instead?